# why does made twice directory websvn

Tags: ubuntu, subversion

Im using `websvn` at the moment of create one repository in svncreate, I can see the same repositories with the same name twice in the view of websvn but in the server I can only see one directory

websvm
[image].

server

[image]

config.php

```
$config->parentPath("/var/lib/svn");
$config->addRepository("Mantencion", "file:///var/lib/svn/Mantencion");
$config->addRepository("Mantenedor", "file:///var/lib/svn/Mantenedor");
$config->setEnscriptPath("/usr/bin");
$config->setSedPath("/bin");
$config->useEnscript();
```

I'm wrong when creating the directory with svncreate or in the `websvm/include/config.php`. Will appreciate any help. Grettings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parentPath` already adds every repository under the given path, so manually adding them again with `addRepository` will result in duplicates, as you have observed.